# Unable to call function from smart contract using web3.js

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

I am trying to call a function from my smart contract using web3 and react.
Here is my code.

```
app.js
    const project=new web3.eth.Contract(Mycontractabi.abi,networkData.address);
    const retailer=await project.getretailer.call();
    console.log(retailer);

contract:
    address public  retailer
    function getretailer() public view returns (address)
    {
        return retailer;
    }
```

Kindly point out what is wrong as I am not able to get retailer address as desired by the code

Comment: maybe instead of this Mycontractabi.abi, just Mycontractabi. `console,log(project)` see what you are getting

Comment: nope, tried your solution, Mycontractabi.abi is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to access a variable from a smart contract using web3.js there is simple
method:

```
contract.methods.variable_name.call().call();
```

So in my case, the modified code will be :

```
const project=new web3.eth.Contract(Mycontractabi.abi,networkData.address);     
const retailer=await project.methods.retailer.call().call();
```

There is no need to call any function just to access a single variable.
We can access any variable directly by using above method.

Comment: small remark: the first parameter is address, abi is the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function like the following.

```
const retailer = await project.methods.retailer().call();
```

If a method has some parameters, you can use:

```
const response = await project.methods.myAnotherMethod(param1, param2).send({from: address});
```

`address` is the current connected wallet address.